# Хочу проиграть несколько аудиодорожек в Python так, как это обычно делается в секвенсоре

Tags: python, python-2.x

Нужно воспроизвести одновременно несколько "дорожек", в которых сэмплы выбираются через randint и проигрываются pyglet. Однако при этом возникает следующая проблема: если закольцовывать модули, то при команде import another_track выполняется только модуль another_track, т.к. он рекурсивный.

Вот пример кода для одного из модулей:

```
import pyglet
import random
import time
import another_track ##Импорт такого же модуля, но с другими файлами для воспроизведения. В таком случае будет проигрываться только импортируемый модуль, а до приведённого ниже кода дело не дойдёт.

def play():

    num=random.randint(1,8) ##Генерирование произвольного числа; если число равно 1, то идём к play1() и т.д. 

    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
    D = 4
    E = 5
    F = 6
    G = 7
    H = 8


    if A==num:
        play1()

    if B==num:
        play2()

    if C==num:
        play3()

    if D==num:
        play4()

    if E==num:
        play5()

    if F==num:
        play6()

    if G==num:
        play7()

    if H==num:
        play8()



def play1():

    N=random.randint(0,1)
    A = 0
    B = 1

##Если A, то делается пауза на 0.3 секунды и возвращаемся к выбору числа в play(); если B, то проигрывается файл, а через полсекунды с начала его воспроизведения возвращаемся обратно к выбору числа в play().
    if A==N:
        time.sleep(0.3)
        play()
    if B==N:
        wavfile = 'D:\\Small Spoon Open.wav'
        sound = pyglet.media.load(wavfile)
        core = pyglet.media.Player()
        core.queue(sound)
        core.play()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        play()
##Далее следуют def play2() и пр. с кодом как в def play1(), но с другим файлом для воспроизведения.
play()
```

Очень желательно, чтобы была возможность запускать несколько подобных рекурсивных модулей одновременно, чтобы иметь возможность менять импортируемые в файл модули-"дорожки".

Comment: Если у вас серьезный проект, то без сумматора не обойтись и на многопоточности не выехать. В этом случае вам нужно читать данные из всех каналов в виде отсчетов, соответствующих текущему квантованию/дискретизации и просто суммировать их, выводя через мастер-канал(ы).

Answer (score 1):

Функции play можно попробовать запускать как процессы, через multiprocessing. Рекурсивное решение выглядит несколько странно? Как вы выходите из цикла проигрывания? Или вы дожидаетесь пока не достигните максимальной глубины рекурсии? Да и импортировать точно такой же модуль, но с другими именами совсем странно. Сделайте один модуль, который умеет проигрывать то что вы хотите. А на вход давайте список файлов, которые вы хотите проигрывать.

Comment: Из цикла проигрывания особой необходимости выходить нет. Если она и возникает, то я либо убиваю процесс питона через диспетчер, либо просто жму стоп в IDE.
Думаю по поводу совета с multiprocessing, читаю про него и пока что не могу понять, как запустить через него несколько play. В принципе, чтобы не тянуть, можно отступить сейчас и попробовать запустить несколько подобных "дорожек" в одном модуле, как вы и посоветовали.